# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' while filtering hashtags from twitter tweets using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

i have been trying to use tweepy to gather some data concerning the coronavirus, i am using python 3.8 and apparently as i have been reading there is a problem concerning bytes type that was not present in python 2. My error is in this line:

**w.writerow(['timestamp', 'tweet_text', 'username', 'all_hashtags', 'followers_count'])**

If anyone can help me modify the code so it works i would be grateful. PS:First time posting a question on stackoverflow be gentle :)

Code:

```
def search_for_hashtags(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, 
hashtag_phrase):

#create authentication for accessing Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

#initialize Tweepy API
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#get the name of the spreadsheet we will write to
fname = '_'.join(re.findall(r"#(\w+)", hashtag_phrase))

#open the spreadsheet we will write to
with open('%s.csv' % (fname), 'wb') as file:

    w = csv.writer(file)

    #write header row to spreadsheet
    w.writerow(['timestamp', 'tweet_text', 'username', 'all_hashtags', 'followers_count'])

    #for each tweet matching our hashtags, write relevant info to the spreadsheet
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag_phrase+' -filter:retweets', \
                               lang="en", tweet_mode='extended').items(100):
        w.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8'), 
    tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'), [e['text'] for e in tweet._json['entities']['hashtags']], tweet.user.followers_count])
if __name__ == '__main__':
search_for_hashtags(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, hashtag_phrase)
```

Comment: You open the file in binary mode but attempt to write a string to it. Change `wb` to `w`.

Comment: good day dear Blshing - hi there firas  many thanks for steppin up the plate with this very interesting thread.  it is great: Blhsing - is the error in this line `with open('%s.csv' % (fname), 'wb') as file: `- look forward to hear from you both - hav a great day

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.